# Building Debian/Ubuntu packages with old gcc: CFLAG adjustment?

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gcc, debian

I need to short circuit some security features in the Debian packaging process.  I explain why here, knowing that your first reactions might be "don't disable security features" and "update your program to compile with new gcc."

I have to use gcc-4.6 to compile some libraries (http://pj.freefaculty.org/Swarm) because that is the last version of gcc that provided the traditional Objective-C API.  After that, gcc removed the traditional headers. Hence, "upgrade your gcc" is not acceptable because we have a very large code base using the traditional Objective-C.

In Ubuntu 17.04, gcc-4.6 is no longer available, but I've found I can install it by pulling an old version from Ubuntu "trusty". It runs fine. I can compile programs and install them the old fashioned `make install` way.

However, I run into a problem when building Debian packages.  When I run `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot`, as I usually do to build a package, I hit a failure because the Debian packaging system has inserted CFLAGS that are not legal in gcc-4.6. In particular, the command line includes `-Wdate-time` and `-fstack-protector-strong`, both of which are not compatible with gcc-4.6.

Here's a piece of the config.log.

```
configure:3878: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3900: gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/pauljohn/LinuxDownloads/Debian/sources/amd64/swarm-Ubuntu17.04/swarm-2.4.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro conftest.c  >&5
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wdate-time'
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong
```

I've inspected the debian directory with the package and I see that those flags are not manually inserted there. From what I can tell, they come along with `dpkg-buildpackage`.

This library I'm trying to compile is, well, an old program. Its one on which we worked, in affiliation with the Santa Fe Institute, about 15-20 years ago. It is not reasonable to rewrite this old code to use the new Objective-C interface, so it is important to live within the restriction of gcc-4.6.

So far, the most useful suggestion I've received is to drop the Debian/Ubuntu architecture and shift to a RedHat based one, where older gcc is more easily tolerated.  In fact, on RedHat 6, gcc-4.6 would be somewhat ahead of the usual, while I can still install gcc-4.6 on RedHat 7, so far as I can tell.  I'd rather not exclude the Ubuntu users, however, by doing that.

Any other ideas about how to navigate this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant documentation is `man 1 dpkg-buildflags`

You basically have two options:

1. override specific *build **features*** of the dpkg buildprocess, hoping to remove the right flags

   ```
   export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="hardening=-stackprotectorstrong reproducible=-timeless"
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
   ```
2. strip specific *build **flags*** from specific build variables

   ```
   export DEB_CPPFLAGS_STRIP="-Wdate-time"
   export DEB_CFLAGS_STRIP="-fstack-protector-string"
   export DEB_CXXFLAGS_STRIP="-fstack-protector-string"
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
   ```

You can also make both ways persistent via configuration files.

Comment: Thanks. Method 1 worked as intended.  The old Swarm project will come back to life, thanks to your help.